# How can I decode this encoded JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript

I have to deal with a very strange JavaScript file. It's called with a standard

```
<script src=XXXX.js type=text/javascript></script>
```

but XXXX.js is somehow packed/encrypted/whatever. The first characters are:

> #@~^3wcAAA==@#@&0;   mDkW

and there is not any pattern in it. there isn't any sign of known function as eval or equivalent.

How can I manage to read it's content? Is it a character set trick?

Answer (score 1):

The creator might have used some kind of javascript obfuscator tool.

Try using the deobfuscator tool-plugin for firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/

Comment: I installed the addon, Which is gone on the mozilla page, but still there in the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20171110010030/https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/10345/javascript_deobfuscator-2.0.4-fx.xpi?filehash=sha256%3Aef2dcc00084ff7a9b128d8174906cf4606fcf353aae2c4b7b41627aeff8eaefa (this works only in Waterfox). But It didn't de-obfuscate the script either

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the first few characters of your string, which could lead you to the right tool. I don't want to spoil the fun here, so I leave the rest to you ;)

If you know the method, I can recommend [Cyber Chef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) to decode your script